# phantom database in Vista

Tags: visual-c++, ms-access, windows-vista

I have a C++/MFC based application that accesses a Microsoft Access database in the folder c:\Program Files\xxx\yyy.

In literally hundreds of other computers running XP, Vista, and 7; the application works just fine.  But on one Vista machine, the apps reads the data from the database and it is completely different then what is actually in the database if I access it via Microsoft Access.  I delete the database from that folder and the application can still access this "phantom" database.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: Program Files has never been a proper location for an Access database, which needs to be user writable. The Program Files folder has been read-only for user-level logons since Win2000, more than a decade ago, and it has been WRONG to store writable data in that folder since then (it was inadvisable before that point, though doable).

Answer (score 2):

The `%ProgramFiles%` folder is virtualized, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387.

Answer (score 0):

Is the data stored local to the user, or on a server somewhere?  Does the data the program on Vista look like it's coming from somewhere else in your information storage database, or is it just making things up?  Some information about structure might help us give you an answer?